# Magento Installation error..redirects to localhost?

Tags: apache, magento, failed-installation

I am unable to login into magento admin.

In magento, (in newest release..)

it needs  proper domain to login ...but how it is 
possible in a local machine...

I found some solution ...in magento forum here...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4337/P15/

They asked to change localhost to http://127.0.0.1

but when tried it redirects to localhost...?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a "fake" domain name, something like magento.dev.  Setup an apache virtual host with this name, and add an entry to your hosts file that points magento.dev to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your localhost to h t t p ://127.0.0.1 and then **delete the cache and session folder located at your /magento/var** folder

Comment: After re-locating my site to a new location it wouldn't work. After changing a few vars in core_config_data, deleting `/var/cache` folder allowed the request I was making to be more up to date and fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a trailing slash when you change it:
e.g. h t t p ://127.0.0.1/

Answer (score 0):

Make `web/seo/use_rewrites = 0` to avoid the xampp url redirection through magento links.